# Find a rational number between $\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ using an algebraic method

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can I find a rational number between $\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ using an algebraic method?

Comment: Have you yourself thought of anything? Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

$\sqrt{5}<q< \sqrt{6}$ so $5<q^2<6$ so ${45\over 9}<q^2<{54\over 9}$ so if we take $q= {7\over 3}$ we are done.

Comment: Elementary ....

Comment: Yes,...........

Answer (score 2):

HINT: prove that $$\sqrt{5}<\frac{12}{5}<\sqrt{6}$$
and this is true since $$125<144<150$$

Comment: ...which is not a hint, and not a method of finding a rational number.

Answer (score 2):

$$5<\frac{m^2}{n^2}<6$$
$$5n^2<m^2<6n^2$$
We must find a square between $5n^2$ and $6n^2$

for $n=3$ we have $45<49<54$ so we can take $m=7$

and $\sqrt{5}<\frac{7}{3}<\sqrt{6}$

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Find a perfect rational square between $5$ and $6$.

$$5<\frac{p^2}{q^2}<6$$ or

$$5q^2<p^2<6q^2.$$

By trial and error, we can use

$$5\cdot3^2=45<7^2=49<6\cdot3^2=54.$$

---

**A systematic procedure:**

The rational must be in $(2.2361,2.4494)$, and the size of this interval is larger than $\dfrac15$. Hence there will be at least one fraction with denominator $q=5$ that can do. Hence $p$ must be in range $(11.1804,12.2474)$, i.e. $p=12$. Indeed, $125<144<150$.

There is no problem using numerical approximations as we take a safey margin and check exact inequalities in the end.

If we now want to play the same game for a rational between $\sqrt{2017}$ and $\sqrt{2018}$, the range is larger than $1/90$ and $p$ must lie in $(4041.993,4042.993)$.

Then, $90^2\cdot2017=16337700<4042^2=16337764<90^2\cdot2018=16345800.$

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty method is to pick a square number between $500$ and $600$ - say $529=23^2$ - then (algebraically!) infer that $5<\left(\frac{23}{10}\right)^2<6$ and so $\sqrt 5< \frac{23}{10}<\sqrt 6$

Comment: Why between $500$ and $600$ ?

Comment: Because multiplying $5$ and $6$ by $100$ is easy and I know there will be a square in that range. Did I say "quick and dirty"? Yes, ok then.

Comment: Yep, but how do you know that $100$ will be enough ?